# TypeScript, Rxjs, SwitchMap, tap wont execute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

`setUsersData()` and `addNewUser()` return `Observable<void>` when finished its job. Even tho this part of the code works fine, function from tap operator wont execute, same if I move the logic to subscribe. Any ideas why it happens?

```
this.userDataService.setUsersData().pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(() => {
    if (name !== undefined) {
      console.log('New User created');
      return this.userDataService.addNewUser(resData.email, resData.localId, name);
    } else {
      console.log('Name is undefined. Skipping user creation.');
      return of();
    }
  }),
  tap(() => {
    console.log('data setted');
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/microblog']);
  })
).subscribe();
```

I tried switching RxJs operators, but it didn't get any better.

Comment: Only reason I can imagine tap won't fire is because the addNewUser call never emits. Assuming it's an http call, make sure you return the httpClient call.

Answer (score 2):

Both my function **addNewUser()** and case with name **undefined** was return *of()*, which doesnt really create an Observable as I learned just now. I chcanged the above to return *of(void 0)* and it works just fine.

Comment: For safety, I'd use `of(null)` instead to avoid edge/corner cases that could come with `undefined`

Answer (score -2):

```
        this.userDataService.setUsersData().pipe(
          take(1),
          switchMap(() => {
            if (name !== undefined) {
              console.log('New User created');
              return this.userDataService.addNewUser(resData.email, resData.localId, name);
            } else {
              console.log('Name is undefined. Skipping user creation.');
              return of();
            }
          }),
          tap(() => {
            console.log('data setted');
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.router.navigate(['/microblog']);
          })
        ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Add some description of what is wrong and how it is fixed in your example to make your answer clearer.  
Also, use Syntax highlighting for code https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting